# Magento 2.3.4 Add custom product attribute value (text-swatch) via REST API

Tags: magento2.3, product-attribute, rest-api

Using Postman, with the following `GET` request I receive data from my custom product attribute:
`rest/V1/products/attributes?&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=attribute_id&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=580`

The response looks like this:

```
"options": [
                {
                    "label": " ",
                    "value": ""
                },
                {
                    "label": "Label 1",
                    "value": "16594"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Label 2",
                    "value": "16597"
                },
```

Now I need to **add a new attribute value** including a label and the description.

Here it says it would be possible (now): https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/release-notes/release-notes-2-3-4-open-source.html

[image]
Can anyone help how the body of my `POST` request should look like? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can see all all API list in your magento instance by below endpoint.

> yourMagento/swagger

**ref:** https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/generate-local.html

[image]

on that interface you can pass your access token and get all list of available api request with example.

for your request you need to pass below params in post request.

**Request Endpoint:** /V1/products/attributes/{attributeCode}/options

**Params:**

```
{
  "option": {
    "label": "string",
    "value": "string",
    "sort_order": 0,
    "is_default": true,
    "store_labels": [
      {
        "store_id": 0,
        "label": "string"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Hope this solution help you to complete you task.

Note: Please make it right and add plus to this solution if this solution work for you.

Thank you.